# How to Running external command (Django) for overriding files in server?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views

After modified inspectdb, I want to run it when index page on web is loaded. So, in my view.py - def index, I´m trying to do the next:

```
def index(request):
 subprocess.Popen("rm /path/app/models.py", shell=True)
 subprocess.Popen("python2.7 /path/manage.py inspectdb_New > /path/app/models.py", shell=True)
 return render_to_response('index/index.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

That is not working. I tried with os.system, subprocess.call as well, but it´s still not working.
For me, at least, looks like I can´t modify models.py in execution time but I don´t know what could be the problem...

Any idea guys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change your models.py while the webserver is running, because models (and other python code) are only loaded at server startup.

Comment: I am not really sure. I think server is consulting model every short time.
I´m trying now:
subprocess.Popen("python2.7 /path/manage.py inspectdb > /path/app/models1.py", shell=True)
  subprocess.Popen("mv /path/models1.py /path/models.py", shell=True)
And this is working sometimes. I suppose when server is consulting models and external command is overriting at the same time, web is crashing, and models finish empty, but in another times works (guessing again, when overriting doesnt match with server´s consulting)...

Comment: No. Models are only loaded on startup. Maybe you explain what you want to achieve. There is probably a better/easier solution.

Comment: Well, I want to update models every time when someone modify ddbb (erasing, adding, modifying tables,...) and this changes will be reflected on the web (web is always launched)

Comment: Maybe you can explain the usecase for this a bit. Why are you modifying the tables outside of django?

Comment: Someone is attaching this db by MySql and another one is attaching it by Django Admin.
Mmmmmmm... I get your point. If someone modify the db by Django Admin or by MySQL, in some point, models should be updated automatically by Django, isn´t? Even if was done by MySQL?

Comment: As I said django will only read the models on server startup. If you change your models.py you have to restart your server.

Comment: Well, Finally I agree. I desist. Thanks for helping me ilse and sorry if I bother you anytime.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts in you question:
a) you want the shell to do something when view function is called. I have alarm beeping already.
b) you want to load new model. It won't gonna happen. You must reload to have new code loaded in (model introspected, etc.). Probably you use runserver command, take a look on Django autoreloader code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/autoreload.py

It tracks files listed by gen_filenames() and reload when something was changed. You model was not listed so the change to the code will not be reflected.

I would touch something or remove .pyc files to force the reloader.

Comment: I check autoreloader, is not what I need. 
I made a custom Django admin so I override inspectdb for generating models.py and admin.py with the specific code I need. Besides, when someone make changes in ddbb schema (by MySQL) I want to generate the new models.py and admin.py dinamically, and those changes should be reflected on web without stopping the server (it should be launched all time).
Finally I desist, I´ll stop the server, launch new inspectdb and I will launch the server again for getting those changes reflected on web...
Anyway, thanks peroksid for your help. Cheers Mate.